# Ubuntu install on newpc

Tags: boot, system-installation

So I am trying to download ubuntu desktop on my new budget pc build. When I plug in the flash drive to install the os, I see an purple haze for ubuntu for a couple seconds until it goes black with a single blinking underscore. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: please explain in your question how the ubuntu flash drive was created, under which OS and was the download verified first together with the version of ubuntu you were attempting to install. [edit] your question - don't add to the comment trail wich is the place for the community to ask **you** questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You've provided no product/release details; nor clues as to if you've removed possible user-procedure errors; ie. did you verify the ISO? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and write to installation media (using the appropriate method for your *unstated* product/release - thus no link provided).   Did you try using the `nomodeset` options on your *unstated* product/release?

Comment: A purple haze usually means that the gui will show up any minute. (At least with mine) A blinking cursor in the top corner means it is trying to boot. That is what I can tell is happening with what you said.

Comment: To state the (very) obvious, this is likely to be one of (1) hardware problem in the computer; (2) problem with the ISO, or (3) usb hardware problem. The first thing I’d do is check if you can use that usb to boot into a live session on a different computer - that at least will tell you if the usb and ISO are functional.